# How create inline button which will allow you to add a this bot to the chat or channel in aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

I want to make a button that will first show the user his chats and channels, and then, when selecting a chat or channel, offer to specify the rights of the bot, which will have the bot in the selected chat. I am using aiogram, but I have not found such a method in the documentation.